# How to get the word of a embedding vector from the pretrained model of hugging face?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I use hugging face's pretrained model, bert, to help me get the meaning of sentence pooling(which means tokenize the sentence and get the average vector of all embedding words). My codes are as follows. I want to get the word which pooling vector refers to.

```py
import torch
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer
model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
# Load the model
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
# input sentence
input_text = "Here is some text to encode"
# from tokenizer to token_id
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_text, add_special_tokens=True)
# input_ids: [101, 2182, 2003, 2070, 3793, 2000, 4372, 16044, 102]
input_ids = torch.tensor([input_ids])
# get the tensors
with torch.no_grad():
    last_hidden_states = model(input_ids)[0] # Models outputs are now tuples
# sentence pooling
last_hidden_states = last_hidden_states.mean(1)
print(last_hidden_states)
# last_hidden_states.shape = [1,768]
```

After this, I want to get the word of this encode vector([1,768]).
Theoretically, I should use this `embedding vecter @ embedding_matrix(size is[ dictionary_dimention ,embedding_dimention])`
And then use the result of above matrix to be the index of the dictionary.
How could I get the embedding_matrix in embedding layers of hugging face, Please.

Comment: Not sure if I get it, but are you looking for the token that is most similar to the sentence embedding vector of a sentence?

Comment: yes，that is what I think

Comment: Did you solve it please

Comment: Yeah, you could see it on hugging face forum:)